# How can I read from a file and then go backwards?

Tags: java, file

I have a large file that has some Data, let's say fruits and info about them.

I will be looking for a keyword ( Apple for example ) 
then I want to read the following 2 lines which are info related to apple and add it to apple. The problem is that some of the fruits have 3 lines following them and I want to be reading three lines as default and in case it was only two lines I want to go backward ( because I will have read the next fruit and will not be abble to add its information to it again )

I am coding in Java.

Comment: Show your code please...What is your file structure...you can use an empty line after each info..And put a check in your code that when you get empty line stop reading the info of current fruit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just read it in a `while` loop like this and process it:

```
    // will contain active fruit
    String currentFruit = null;
    while (true) {
        if (currentFruit == null) {// only read to fruit if there is no active fruit
            currentFruit = reader.readLine();
            if (currentFruit == null) // end of file
                break;
        }

        if (currentFruit != null && isFruit(currentFruit)) {
            // read first line
            String line1 = reader.readLine();
            // check for end of file
            if (line1 == null)
                break;

            // read second line
            String line2 = reader.readLine();
            // check for end of file
            if (line2 == null)
                break;

            // read third line
            String line3 = reader.readLine();
            if (line3 == null || isFruit(line3)) {
                // third line was actually a fruit, so set currentFruit to line3
                // and clear line 3
                currentFruit = line3;
                line3 = null;
            } else {
                // clear fruit
                currentFruit = null;
            }

            // process fruit
            processFruit(currentFruit, line1, line2, line3);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you reading the file in the stream in Java, in that case, we can use  Mark, reset function to achieve this.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html#mark%28int%29

from the documentation:

mark
public void mark(int readlimit)
See the general contract of the mark method of InputStream.
Overrides:
mark in class FilterInputStream
Parameters:
readlimit - the maximum limit of bytes that can be read before the mark position becomes invalid.
See Also:
reset()
reset

public void reset()
           throws IOException
See the general contract of the reset method of InputStream.
If markpos is -1 (no mark has been set or the mark has been invalidated), an IOException is thrown. Otherwise, pos is set equal to markpos.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer for OP's question but a recommendation. You don't need to go backwards in file. I would just buffer the lines and keep processing. Here is a pseudo for what I mean (100 should be enough for your case):

```
unprocessedLines = EMPTY_ARRAY_OF_STRING;

till end of file: {
 read 100 lines + unprocessedLines in the buffer
 unprocessedLines = process() // maybe the last 2 lines needs more info
}
// so on..
```